# How do I get binary data from pdf created in libharu?

Tags: c, pdf, libharu

I have a basic C function, which creates a pdf and then writes it to the disc with `HPDF_SaveToFile(pdf, filename)` where `pdf` is an instance of `HPDF_Doc`.

But now I want to change the function behaviour so instead of writing to disc, it would return pdf as binary, which I will work with elsewhere.

How do I get binary from `HPDF_Doc` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, here's how I did it:

```
HPDF_SaveToStream(pdf);
unsigned int streamSize = HPDF_GetStreamSize(pdf);
unsigned char* buffer = malloc(streamSize * sizeof(buffer));
HPDF_Stream_Read(pdf->stream, buffer, &streamSize);
```

this way `buffer` variable will contain the binary